# How to select only particular value in array?

Tags: javascript

I have `var colors = ["green", "blue", "red", "yellow" ]`. I want to check if there is "red", then return only that particular element from that array. But my code returns all the elements in the array.

```
for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++){
    if ((colors[i])=== "red") {
    return colors[i];
  }
 }
```

Comment: `return colors.indexOf('red') > -1 ? 'red' : undefined;`

Comment: It looks good. It should return the element.

Comment: Thanks. I actually get illegal return statement.

Comment: `return` can only be used inside functions. If this code is not inside a function then it's unclear where exactly you want to return to. Can you elaborate?

Comment: [See this](http://jsfiddle.net/q2m61k28/2/)!

Comment: You have to define function to return some value otherwise you can store your value in some varible, You have two options for it.

Comment: I think it must work,please see  [pure javascript colors.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) or [jquery $.grep](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/)

Comment: Thanks all. Can some one explain what is happening in  `> -1 ? 'red' : undefined`.

Comment: @Ann in `colors.indexOf('red')`, if `red` is not found in the array it will return `-1`. So, if it's found, it will return the index of it in that array.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing's wrong with your code..

```
function getColor(color)
{
  colors = ["green", "blue", "red", "yellow" ]

  for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++){
      if ((colors[i])=== color) {
      return colors[i];
    }
   }
}

getColor('red'); // returns 'red';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
colors = ["green", "blue", "red", "yellow" ]

function getColor(c){
     return colors.indexOf(c)> -1? colors[colors.indexOf(c)]: undefined;
}
document.write(getColor('red'));
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++){
    if (colors[i] == "red") {
        return colors[i];
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3pk9qc51/), FIDDLE alerts the selected item

You have to wrap the for loop inside a function that return the value.

Example :

```
$(function () {
    var colors = ["green", "blue", "red", "yellow"];

    function GetItem() {
        for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
            if ((colors[i]) === "red") {
                return colors[i];
            }
        }
    }

    alert(GetItem());
});
```

Hope this works for you

Answer (score 0):

If it is not inside a function. break the loop when the condition is satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

For a start, you need to break and assign, or save the key.

```
var key;
for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++){
    if ((colors[i])=== "red") {
        key = i;
        break;
    }
 }
 color = colors[key];
```

But you could use [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) instead.

```
if (colors.indexOf('red') !== -1) {
    var key = colors.indexOf('red');
    var color = colors[key];
}
```